# Combining json in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the below code

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(*******************)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "SELECT schema_old FROM table_1 where ingestion_id=1;"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

schema_output='\n'.join(''.join(elems) for elems in result)
json_data=json.loads(schema_output)
print(json_data)

sql1 = "SELECT schema_new FROM table_1 where ingestion_id=1;"
cursor.execute(sql1)
result1 = cursor.fetchall()

schema_output1='\n'.join(''.join(elems) for elems in result1)
json_data1=json.loads(schema_output1)
```

where:

```
json_data= [{'name': 'status', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': 'address', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]
json_data1= [{'name': 'phone', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]
```

I want to combine the jsons: `json_data + json_data1` , so that the final json is:

```
[{'name': 'status', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': 'address', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}, {'name': 'phone', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]
```

I tried doing:

```
thejson1["data"].extend(thejson2["data"])
```

and

```
c = dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

But it did not work.

Comment: From what I can see with that formatting, `json_data + json_data1` would be enough.  You have two lists of dictionaries, they could be summed just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? You got an error, the result was unexpected, something else?

Comment: Once you have read the json data with `json`, it is **just** an ordinary Python data structure of nested lists and dicts, which you work with **the exact same way** that you would if you had gotten the same data **in any other way**. The question is "I have two lists; how do I concatenate them?", and the answer is `json_data + json_data1` - exactly as you already show. The other attempts make no sense at all, as you should realize if you actually *think about the data that you have*.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Like @Klas mentioned just the below was enough:

```
mjson=json_data+json_data1
```